# How do you set a image pixel color in Imagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

i am using Imagick for image processing. I am unable to find any native function to set a particular pixel color while there is one to get one. I mean,

```
$image->getimagepixelcolor($i, $j);
```

will return an object to get the color of pixel at `($i, $j)`  but there doesn't seems to be a method to set color. Something like this,

```
$image->setimagepixelcolor($i, $j, "#FFFFFF");
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `floodFillPaintImage`?

Comment: My sever uses a bit of obsolete version of Imagemagick. SO the function is not supported. On the side note, I don't think the function exactly does what I need.

Comment: Do you have the ImagickDraw class? It has all kinds of functions for drawing stuff.

Comment: Otherwise you could use GD: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 5):

There would be no `setImagePixelColor` method on the `Imagick` class. I can't speak of why there isn't one, but one can achieve the same effects by invoking the [ImagickPixelIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagickpixeliterator.php), or [ImagickDraw](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagickdraw.php) class.

**Iterator Example:**

The proper way would be to iterator over the pixels in an image, alter a pixels color, then sync the data back to the image.

```php
$image = new Imagick('source.png');

// Grab iterator
$iterator = $image->getPixelIterator();
// Seek to row at Y
$iterator->setIteratorRow($j);
// Get pixel in row
$row = $iterator->getCurrentIteratorRow();
// Seek to pixel at X
$pixel = $row[$i];
// Set Color
$pixel->setColor('#FFFFFF');
// Sync data back to image
$iterator->syncIterator();

$image->writeImage('out.png');
```

**Draw Example:**

The other option would be to draw the new pixel on top of the existing image.

```php
$image = new Imagick('source.png');
$draw  = new ImagickDraw();
$color = new ImagickPixel('#FFFFFF');

// Set fill color
$draw->setFillColor($color);
// Draw a point at X,Y
$draw->point($i,$j);
// Apply the drawing on top of the image
$image->drawImage($draw);

$image->writeImage('dest.png');
```

Of course with Object's in PHP, you can simple extend the core Imagick object, and create your own `setImagePixelColor` method

```php
class MyImagick extends Imagick 
{
   /**
    * Alter image by defining the color of a single pixel
    *
    * @param integer $x
    * @param integer $y
    * @param string $color
    */
   public function setImagePixelColor($x,$y, $color) 
   {
      //... Apply one of the methods here
      $draw  = new ImagickDraw();
      $draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel($color));
      $draw->point($x,$y);
      $this->drawImage($draw);
   }
}
```